# ¿Cómo cerrar ventana padre cuando se llama a ventana hija en JAVA?

Tags: java, netbeans

En el proyecto debe haber varias ventanas (la de Login, Menu, Actividad1, Actividad2, etc.)

He estado investigando y encontré que se podía poner lo siguiente en el método que se deseara de la ventana principal (en mi caso la de login):

```
public void acceder() {
    Menu vMenu = new Menu(){
        @Override
        public void dispose(){
            super.dispose();
        }
    };
    vMenu.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
}
```

Quiero abrir otra ventana desde la ventana de menú, tengo el mismo código en los eventos de algunos botones solo que tengo un inconveniente y es que ya cuando estoy en la ventana *Actividad1* puedo cerrar y se muestra la ventana de *Menú* y en esta puedo llamar a la ventana *Actividad2* y cerrarla para volver a la ventana de *Menú* pero al cerrar la ventana de *Menú* ya no se muestra la ventana de *Login* a pesar de que en las propiedades de todas las ventanas está `DISPOSE` de `defaulCloseOperation`.

¿Talvez alguien tiene idea de lo que estaría mal y tenga que modificar en las propiedades del JFrame o en el código?

Comment: Hola Santiago, me parece que el camino más sencillo, es tener un método que reciba un frame y lo pase a **setVisible( true );** y a los restantes lo contrario, algo como: 
    **Frame listaVentanas[] = new Frame[ 5 ]; 
    public void mostrarVentana( Frame ven ) {     
        for( Frame ventana : listaVentanas ) { 
            if( ven.equals( ventana ) { 
                ventana.setVisible( true ); 
            } 
            else { 
                ventana.setVisible( false );
            }
        }
    }**